# jquery dropdown menu redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I need a dropdown menu for a school project, i dont know much about javascript so im asking here. I just need to add a redirect when an option is clicked from a dropdown menu. I pasted the files to pastie http://pastie.org/6365493 and http://pastie.org/6365495

Comment: You've posted a lot of code; this question would be easier to answer if you made it clear what wasn't working with your current solution and were more specific about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML:
<select id="selectbox">
    <option value="https://www.yahoo.com/" selected>Option1</option>
    <option value="https://www.google.co.in/">Option2</option>
    <option value="https://www.gmail.com/">Option3</option>
</select>


JAVASCRIPT:
<script>  
    jQuery(function () {
        $("#selectbox").change(function () {
            location.href = $(this).val();
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: obtrusive javascript (lead to xss) think about it

Answer (score 0):

Here is something very very simple i wrote for you:

http://jsbin.com/ayomar/3

HTML:

```
  <select id="redirect">
    <option>Where to cer?</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Home</option>
  </select>
```

JAVASCRIPT: JQuery

```
$("#redirect").on("change", function() {
   var self = $(this);
   // console.log(self.val());
   window.location.href = self.val();
});
```

Comment: What? you degraded my score for that are you serious??? It's a full example that you can check it.

Comment: just update your answer with your example code, so I can remove the downvote